# Move all consonants in a string until the first vowel is met

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

I'm trying to move all consonants in order at the end of a string as soon as the first vowel is encountered.

For example, with this code the goal I would like to achieve is to have the word "atch"

```
sentence = 'chat'
splitted = sentence.chars
splitted.each do |letter|
  %w[a e i o u].include?(letter) ? break : splitted << splitted.shift
end

p splitted.join
```

But what I finally get is "hatc"
Any suggestions on how to implement this?

Comment: Assuming the string contains a vowel, you could write `i = str.index(/[aeiou]/i); str[i..-1] + str[0,i]`. To change the string in place, `str.replace(str[i..-1] + str[0,i])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```rb
vowels = %w[a e i o u]
sentence = 'chat'
splitted = sentence.chars
right_part = []

sentence.each_char do |letter|
  vowels.include?(letter) ? break : right_part << splitted.shift
end

new_sentence = (splitted + right_part).join

p new_sentence # => "atch"
```